# What is the intersection of $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know what is the intersection of a interval of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{N}$. Example:

\begin{equation}
(a,b)\cap \mathbb{N}
\end{equation} or

\begin{equation}
\left[a,b\right]\cap  \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}

The resulting set only has natural numbers?.

Thanks.

Comment: If $a,b$ are not integers then the two different things you wrote are equivalent.  Yes, that intersection includes only the positive integers appearing in the specified interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a subset of natural number, which can possibly be an empty set.

For $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{N}$ They are the natural number that are at least $a$ and at most $b$.

For $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{N}$ They are the natural number that are more than $a$ and less than $b$.

Remark:
Btw, I think you meant $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ rather than $\in$.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the correction, it was effectively $\subset$.